# Having trouble getting a script to run again when resizing the window

Tags: jquery

I don't know what I'm doing well enough to be able to figure out why the height isn't being recalculated when resizing the window. Also, I would like the calculation to run seperately for each of the three schools.

Any help would be appreciated: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/kmwmf/

```
$(window).resize( function() {

    var $school = $('.content ul'),
        $campus = $('.content ul p'),
        campusHeight = 0;

    $school.each( function() {
        $campus.each( function() {
            if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
                campusHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });
    });

    $campus.height(campusHeight);        
    console.log(campusHeight);

}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: Don't understand your question. You like when resize window, for each school make separate resize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving it myself: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/kmwmf/7/

Removing the inline style attribute before measuring the height ensured that the code worked correctly when resizing the window.

```
$(window).resize( function() {

    var $school = $('.content ul'); 

    $school.each( function() {
        var $campus = $(this).find('p'),
            campusHeight = 0;

        $campus.each( function() {
            $(this).removeAttr('style');
            if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
                campusHeight = $(this).height();
            } 
        });

        $campus.height(campusHeight);
    });   

}).trigger('resize');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code is currently doing:

```
var $school = $('.content ul'),    // select all school ul elements
    $campus = $('.content ul p'),  // select ALL campus paragraphs
    campusHeight = 0;

$school.each( function() {         // iterate over the schools
    $campus.each( function() {     // iterate over ALL campuses, not just
                                   // the ones for the current school
```

The following should do a separate calculation for each school:

```
$(window).resize( function() {

    $('.content ul').each( function() { // iterate over the school ul elements
        var campusHeight = 0,
            $campus = $('p', this);     // get campuses for current school
        $campus.each( function() {      // iterate over current campuses
            if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
                campusHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $campus.height(campusHeight);   // set height for campuses
        console.log(campusHeight);      // in current school
    });    

}).trigger('resize');
```

In my code I've elimated the `$schools` variable since you can tack the outer `.each()` directly onto the initial `$('.content ul')`. Similarly you could eliminate the the `$campus` variable by chaining the height setting code on the end of the inner `.each()`:

```
        $('p', this).each( function() {
            if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
                campusHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        }).height(campusHeight);
```

Comment: That works on page load, but unfortunately there is no recalculating of size when resizing the window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do, iterate campuses of each school separately to evaluate height:

```
$(window).resize( function() {

  var $school = $('.content ul');

$school.each( function() {
    $campus = $(this).find('p');
    campusHeight = 0;
    $campus.each( function() {
        if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
            campusHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
     $campus.height(campusHeight);
});



  console.log(campusHeight);

}).trigger('resize');
```

This has only resize the school campuses separately. For recalculating height, see this edit please:

```
 $(window).resize( function() {

    var $school = $('.content ul');

    $school.each( function() {
    $campus = $(this).find('p');
    campusHeight = 0;
    $campus.css('height', ''); //forces to remove height to recalculate new height

    $campus.each( function() {
        if($(this).height() > campusHeight) {
            campusHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });
     $campus.height(campusHeight);
});



  console.log(campusHeight);

}).trigger('resize');
```

Comment: That works on page load, but unfortunately there is no recalculating of size when resizing the window. Any ideas?

Comment: joshnh, please check the edit, hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the ammendment, luckily I have already found a solution.